# Redirecting URL with parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, seo

I want to redirect URL:

```
prolist.php?id=1297&lang=en
```

to that:

```
details.php?id=1297
```

But id don't want to redirect other URL's that haven't "lang=en" parameter at the end of URL.

Comment: So you want to implement a `RewriteCond` that matches a precise pattern against the query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to implement a condition for your redirection ruile that matches a precise pattern against the query string:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)&lang=en$
RewriteRule ^/?prolist\.php$ /details.php?id=%1 [QSD,R=301]
```

And maybe you also want to implement an internal rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)&lang=en$
RewriteRule ^/?prolist\.php$ /details.php?id=%1 [QSD,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^/?details\.php$ /prolist.php?id=%1&lang=en [L]
```